# Is there a possibility to delay updates (user _apt)?

Tags: apt, update-manager

I have the following problem:

Sometimes, I'm running some program requiring a lot of CPU power using `wine`.

Unfortunately, Linux updates (processes running under the user `_apt`) are starting rather often while I'm running that program.

The Linux updates (processes running under the user `_apt`) also require a lot of CPU power (`top` shows 99.9%) and the program does not work correctly any more (the picture becomes jerky etc...) because the CPU power is not enough.

Question: Is there a method to forbid Linux updates while the program is running so the updates are delayed until I finished running that program?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
forbid_or_allow_updates forbid
wine ~/programs/my_program.exe
forbid_or_allow_updates allow
```

... but I don't know if something like `forbid_or_allow_updates` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is (but not exactly in the way you suggest).

From `Show Applications` (the 9 dot icon at the bottom of the dock or by pressing the left <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, select `Software and Updates` select `Never` from the `Automatically check for updates` drop down for as long as you are performing intensive CPU activity then, when you are ready to receive updates again, reselect your choice as required.

[image]

Comment: Surely there's a way to do that from the command line so that it can be scripted?

Comment: it would take as many commands to implement a script as it would to simply just open `Software and Updates` and select the options as outlined from there as well as being a lot safer.

Comment: Opening `Software and Updates` and selecting the options requires a human to perform those steps, sit in front of the screen, wait for the program to finish, and then revert them. Depending on the number of times this procedure will be performed, this may be considerably more expensive and error prone than implementing and testing a script.

Answer (score 0):

If Unattended Upgrades and your application are competing for CPU, change the priority of one of them so your preferred application always gets enough CPU to prevent stuttering and jittering. It's NOT an A vs B decision -- the system will happily balance resources if it knows your priorities. There's a tool for this: See `man nice` or `man renice`.

- It might be as simple as starting your application with a higher priority so other applications wait for free cycles. For example:

`nice -n -10 my_application`  (negative number = less nice = higher priority)

- You can apply niceness to systemd services (like Unattended Upgrades). It's a simple matter of adding a `nice` value to the ExecStart line. There are two services to make nicer: `apt-daily.service` and `apt-daily-upgrade.service`. DON'T edit the original file in /lib/system, which will be overwritten by the next upgrade. Instead, use a systemd override .conf file. See the instructions at https://superuser.com/questions/1447351/set-niceness-value-in-a-systemd-user-service.
- If you REALLY want to get out the heavy firepower and completely inhibit Unattended Upgrades, use systemd to stop/start it's timers. Keep in mind that it's up to YOU to restart those timers.

`systemctl stop(start) apt-daily.timer` (prevents automated apt updates)
`systemctl stop(start) apt-daily-upgrade.timer` (prevents automated apt upgrades)